# How do I get a file object from a method using my template?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my model i have a method like so:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    #...
    def get_file(self):
        file = open('path/to/file','r')
        return File(file)
```

I am attempting to access this method and the file object in my template like so:

```
{{ content.get_file.url }}
```

I am not getting any error but I am also not getting any output. It just returns nothing where there should be a url.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is this `File` you speak of?

Comment: Does the File-class have an url member? (not sure where that came from..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for doesn't make sense. If you are opening an file in an arbitrary location there will be no correlating URL (that Django knows about, at least).

My suggestion would be to simply provide a `get_file_url` method too.

Comment: I was reading from here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/files/#the-file-object and later I have found this: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11597 so have worked around my problem

Comment: How frustranting - incorrect docs are worse than no docs!
Glad you got it solved.